# How to make a GET request from node server to Flask API

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, flask

I'm having a hard time connecting my Node API to my Flask API, I keep getting an `Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 10.209.234.2:80`

I've got a Node application that does a simple get request to a Flask API as follows:

```
    var options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        url: 'http://localhost:5000/api/v1/counts/health-check',
    }

    await axios(options)
    .then(function (resp) {
        console.log('SUCCESS, response below')
        console.log(resp)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log('ERROR, error below')
        console.log(error)
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Not an error but see below")
    })
```

My Flask API route is built as follows:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response 
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow 
from marshmallow import fields
import psutil 
from datetime import datetime 
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
app.config['CORS_HEADERS'] = 'Content-Type'
CORS(app)

@app.route('/api/v1/counts/health-check', methods = ['GET'])
def health_check():
    try:
        print("Endpoint {} called".format('/api/v1/counts/health-check'))
        uptime = datetime.now() - datetime.fromtimestamp(psutil.boot_time())
        uptime = uptime.total_seconds()
        message = 'OK'
        timestamp = datetime.now()
        response = jsonify({"uptime": uptime,
                            "message": message,
                            "timestamp": timestamp})
        return make_response(response, 201)
    except Exception as e:
        print('The following exception occured: {}'.format(e))
```

When I make the call to the Flask route through postman it works just fine, but through the node server it keeps timing out. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the Node.JS server is hitting the API route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this and it's simple: don't use axios if you're working behind a corporate proxy! Using a simple promise call worked it out and the GET request works.

Something like this should do it:

```
    let url = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/v1/counts/health-check";
    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
}).then(response => console.log(response.json()));
```

I'm not 100% sure why this works, but my guess it has to do with the fact that axios uses proxy by default. Hope this helps people with similar problems in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention using Postman, have you tried using it to generate the Code for the API request? You can generate the Javascript you need and try that in your solution.