# Permission issue when running a python script via Node spawn child process

Tags: python, node.js, file-permissions, child-process

I have a Node application, one function of which involves executing a python script. The python script processes some data in a file, and then writes parsed data to a new `sample.json` file.

Then Node uses that `sample.json` to send data to a database. Please see the code below.

`script.js`

```js
await getPythonScriptStdout('./script.py').then(async (output) => {
        let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', '/sample.json'))
        let output_object = JSON.parse(rawdata);
        console.log(output_object)
        //do stuff here with output_object
        fs.unlinkSync(path.join(__dirname, '..', '/sample.json'))
})

function getPythonScriptStdout (pythonScriptPath) {
        const python = spawn('python3', [pythonScriptPath]);
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            python.on('exit', (code) => {
                console.log('python process finished, exit code:', code)
                resolve()
            });
        })
    }
```

`script.py`

```py
table = gettable() # for simplicity I'm skipping the definition of this function for this post

# Serializing json
json_object = json.dumps(table)

# Writing to sample.json
with open(os.getcwd() + '/sample.json', "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(json_object)
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

This runs just fine on my Macbook, just fine on a Windows PC, but fails on Windows Server or on a Raspberry Pi. After much testing I've found out that there seems to be some problem with correctly executing the python script from node (on those devices that it didn't work on). Running just the python script itself DOES WORK on ALL devices I test on, just when executing the script from node it immediately fails with exit code 2, which is what led me to believe it's some kind of permission issue of Node executing Python scripts.

I've also tested this with instead of the python script writing to file, it outputs the json in stdout and Node gets that. Same result with this method, the python script when run by itself works, but when executed by Node, on certain machines works but on others doesn't.

If anybody has some advice or suggestions it would be very welcome, thank you so much. I've been troubleshooting this for a few days now and have not been able to come to a solution myself.

Comment: You could consider starting a minimal flask server with some api endpoint that runs the function and returns the json. Then, you only need to access the api endpoint in node and not worry about running the python. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63528786/how-to-make-a-get-request-from-node-server-to-flask-api

Comment: @Tim Hm I guess this would work well as a work-around, hadn't thought of that, thanks for the idea!